# Inline block not being applied

Tags: html, css, django

Im kinda new to HTML/CSS and im trying to align images side by side. I'm trying to use inline block but it's not being applied. Could someone please point out where i am going wrong.

Parent class;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/Css/Parent.css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="AllCardViews">
      {% block Movies/Shows %}{% endblock Movies/Shows %}
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Child Class;

```
{% extends "Movies/Parent.html" %}

{% block Movies/Shows %}
{% for Movie in Movies %}
    <div class="CardView">
        <img src= '{{ Movie.Image }}' align = "middle" alt="">
    </div>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock Movies/Shows %}
```

Corresponding Css;

```
.AllCardViews {
    width: 170px;
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 80%;
    margin: 5px 20px;
    margin-left: 300px;
    margin-right: 300px;
    margin-top: 300px
}

.AllCardViews .CardView img {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Above you can see that i'm trying to specify where i want to use inline block as im selecting both classes yet it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: img is already an inline level element so adding inline-block will change nothing

Comment: @TemaniAfif How would i change that? , i removed `align = "middle"`.

Comment: change what ? ..

Comment: I think I got it, inline-block should be applied to `.CardView` not image

Comment: @TemaniAfif Just tried it, didnt seem to make a change. I also forgot to mention in the post that the image size went back to the original instead of staying to the asigned `max-width: 80%;` ive put.